# How can i limit memory of my micronaut server app

Tags: micronaut

I am running a small webserver-app using micronaut.

This is how i start it.

```
nohup ./jdk-15/bin/java -jar microtao-0.1-all.jar>./microtao.log &
```

I think it uses too much memory.

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem | head
root      7818  0.1  1.0 4727872 89732 pts/1   Sl   13:55   0:08 ./jdk-15/bin/java -jar microtao-0.1-all.jar
```

How can I limit the memory to 500 mb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the max heap size for the JVM...

```
java -Xmx512m -jar microtao-0.1-all.jar
```

Comment: The question was "How can I limit the memory to 500 mb?" and limiting the heap size is a way to do that, as described above.  Separate from that, it might prove helpful to profile the app and find out what is using all the memory.